# C++ Vector of Pointers, too many passes?

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, class, polymorphism, containers

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this seg-fault problem for hours now.

I have a card game in C++, four players. A player (base class) can either be a computer or a human (derived classes). To store them, I have another class called playerContainer, which has its own functions and uses a private member vector of player pointers.

```
std::vector<Player*> players_;
```

When I add a new player to the vector, I do something like this:

```
Human *newPlayer = new Human();
container.add(newPlayer);
```

Where add is:

```
void playerContainer::add(Player* newPlayer) {
   players_.push_back(newPlayer);
}
```

And then I have one class called gameLogic which has a private member playerContainer and performs the player initialization (among several other things).

However, I'm getting seg faults after trying to make incorporate it into an MVC implementation.

On the GUI, you click a button to start the game. The button calls the window's startGame function, which gathers parameters and then calls its private member Model class's startGame, which then calls its private member gameLogic's initializePlayer function, which then calls its private member playerContainer's add function. At that point the program will break.

On a bit of testing, I found that it would not seg fault if I saved a step. For example, if I gave the window object a gameLogic object, and then called its initializePlayer function and so forth, the program would proceed normally without error.

I'm certain there's a better solution than to combine the Model and gameLogic classes as they are already quite bloated. May anyone provide some insight?

Also, if this is any bit confusing, please ask me to clarify. I did my best to explain clearly, but with so many different classes involved, it gets difficult to do so.

EDIT: Can't try replacing Player* with int, the code's way too huge for me to be able to do this in any timely fashion.

I HAVE tried valgrind, but the log was huge and generally unhelpful. Or at the very least, I couldn't understand much of it. For those who want to take a look, here's a scribd link:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/60210916/Memory-Leak

The seg fault is being raised on the playerContainer's add function, on the push_back line.

I'll try my hand at the debugger...

Comment: What happens if you don't use Player* in your vector, but just use int's instead. Commenting out any code that uses Player*'s directly and running will show you whether you are using an uninitialized player, or if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: If you're on a supported platform, run your program through `valgrind`.

Comment: please show some more code. e.g. how do you use the added players in your implementation. How do you free your pointers etc...

Comment: I think you should start finding where the segmentation fault is raised

Comment: Run your program though the debugger, and when you get to your segfault, do a back-trace which will show not only where your segfault occurred, but what the state of the stack was when the segfault happened.  Then you can step back through the stack and see what functions and calls were made ... that should help you isolate where the segfault is occurring.

Comment: Edited post with response to most things. The only thing I didn't do was include more code, if only because I have no idea what would be useful in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Model, somewhere, but before initializePlayer is called, actually allocates the playerContainer?

Comment: No, I can't say I'm entirely certain. For whatever reason though, using the exact syntax of adding a gameLogic object to the window leaves everything fine. I don't understand the difference between how I'm doing it with the window and how I'm doing it with the model.

Comment: That is hard to tell without more code. How do you declare and allocate the playerContainer, and how do you access it?

Comment: playerContainer uses the implicit constructor and only has the one private member `std::vector<Player*> players_`.

Accessing its members are done with an overloaded [] operator, which returns players_[i].

Creating the playerContainer itself is only done as a private member of gameLogic, which does pretty much this:
    `class gameLogic {
       private:
           playerContainer container;
       }`